# What is the correct way to run this class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        for item in my_list:
            print(item)
```

How can I set a variable to run `MyClass()` since it requires `my_list`?

I have tried `MyClass = MyClass()` but I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in an iterable as the first argument; a list for example:

```
instance = MyClass(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

but anything that can be looped over will do; so a tuple, a string, a dictionary, a file object will all do.

Don't assign the result back to `MyClass`; then you'd rebind that name from the original class to the newly-created instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: If I pass a class with a string like this: `MyClass("string")` I get `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. Is it wrong?

Comment: @zachgates: Yes, you can; the loop will print each character in the string separately.

Comment: @zachgates: You got your import and the class mixed up then.

Answer (score 2):

Ummm... just submit an iterable as the `my_list` argument?

Demo:

```
>>> example = MyClass([1, 2, 3])
1
2
3
```